# How to query tables in Rails console

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I have this application which I'm messing around with. (didn't create it, but trying fiddle with it and learn more about querying it, etc).

So, it has a lot of tables.

So, when I go into console, and ask User.first, I get the first one obviously.

(btw, you capitalize it and make it singular, right? even though tables are lower-case and plural?)

But when I ask for, say Tutor_appointment.first, this is what I get

```
`NameError: uninitialized constant Tutor_appointment from (pry):25:in `<main>'
```

Or even say, User_profile.first, again same thing:

```
`NameError: uninitialized constant User_Profile from (pry):30:in `<main>'
```

Why do I get these errors?

These are actual tables, and they do have data in it.

Am I querying the camelcase tables wrongly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you're correct that database table names are generally lowercase and plural. The model class names that represent those tables are uppercase and singular and no underscores.

In the console when you're doing `User.first`, it's not going directly to the database, it's actually calling `.first()` on the User model, a class. So you need to find the models for the tutor_appointments and user_profiles tables, and they're likely called `TutorAppointment` and `UserProfile`.

Comment: Franciso, hm, how do I query the table itself then? When I ran users.first right now, it gave me `NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
from (pry):36:in `<main>'`

Comment: But `User.first` works right? How about `TutorAppointment.first` and `UserProfile.first` ?

Comment: btw, thanks for explaining that I was actually querying the User model itself. Didn't realize that. So, yes, TutorAppointment and UserProfile query worked after that. So, for that the answer is accepted because you at least explained why my query wasn't working.

Comment: But still wondering how to query the table itself properly, if you don't mind explaining why users.first didn't work.

Comment: `users.first` doesn't work because there's no `users` variable in scope. In Ruby on Rails you access the database through an ORM called ActiveRecord. The User, TutorAppointment and UserProfile models inherit from a class called ActiveRecord::Base which has all the magic for connecting and querying the database.

Comment: BTW, that was assuming you have a typical setup. If you want to run sql queries you can do `User.find_by_sql("select u.name from users")` for example.

Comment: so, for querying purposes, you query models names?

Comment: Yes, because you're not really querying with sql, you're calling methods on a class that eventually convert to sql and return you the results. Check out this link for a lot more you can do http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: btw, thanks again for explaining all this. I have another question about querying both TutorAppointments and Users models. Hope you can help out on that, maybe? Will write it up in few minutes.

Comment: oh, I didn't realize that I was calling methods on a class that would eventually convert it to sql. Yeah, yeah, yeah, I've read that guide ... sorta, kinda ... I mean, yes, but you know how it is when you're somewhat a novice and things sorta go over your head till someone says, no, it's this, not that, etc.